# Consume REST API, Send data using x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I am trying to consume a web service to get a token. It is a POST service and I must send data using x-www-form-urlencoded, but I am not sure how to do it. I have the following code, but an error "400 Bad Request" returns. I'm using jersey.api.client and gson. The service returns a JSON object.

```
public VOToken getToken() {

    String uri = "https://login.mypurecloud.com/oauth/token";

    VOToken voToken = null;

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    System.out.println(getAuthorizationHeaderString());

    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);

    Form form = new Form();
    form.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    WebResource.Builder builder = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
    builder.header("Authorization", getAuthorizationHeaderString());
    builder.entity(form);

    //Response
    ClientResponse clientResponse = builder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class);
    clientResponse.bufferEntity();
    String jsonString = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);

    if(clientResponse.getStatus() == 200 ) {

        voToken = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, VOToken.class);
        System.out.println(">> Access_token: "+ voToken.getAccess_token());
    }

    return voToken;
}

public String getAuthorizationHeaderString() {
    String clientId = "32ef8d9c-######################";
    String clientSecret = "6-M5A8Y06##################";
    String authorizationHeaderString = "";

    try {
        String encodedData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        authorizationHeaderString = "Basic " + encodedData;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return authorizationHeaderString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Shankha057. It works fine now!

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` and not `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE`.
 Also in your `ClientResponse` change the media type to `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`